# PHP Object-nested data manipulation

Tags: php, oop

I have two classes, `A` and `B`, that work together, like this:

- Global scope instantiate `A`object.
- `A`object instantiate `B`object as a *public* property.
- `B`object contains `C`array as a *public* property.

**QUESTION**:

How do I manipulate `C`array from global scope, without copying it, AND without explicitly pointing at `A->B->C` for each operation?

*PS: This is a minimal example. My chains could end up rather long, if no solution exists.*

Comment: Create a getter function?

Comment: @u_mulder. A getter, containing what? ... I won't copy the array ...

Comment: If you need values of `C` from class `A` - create `A::getC { return A->B->C; }`  If you need to set values of `C` from class `A` - create `A::setC($key, $value) {  A->B->C[$key] = $value; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php). You will have to use A->B->C only once per scope.

```
$c = &$A->b->c;
$c['something'] = 'somethiing else';
```

Comment: Can that technique pass a reference to A, inside B and global scope only needs to reference the reference in A ... as in each class can pass the reference forward in the chain? ... reference to reference to reference?

Comment: Objects are always passed by reference in PHP and you have to explicitly use 'clone' construction to copy them.

Comment: And yes, you can do that. ;-)